# Are recursion functions not supported in .erb templates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, erb

Okay so basically I have something like this:

**someView.erb**

```
 <ul>
    <% @objects.each do |object| %>
      <%= printAllChildObjects(object) %>
    <% end %>
 </ul>
```

**app.rb**

```
def printAllChildObjects(object)
   "<li>#{object.attributes['name']}</li>"
    if object.children.first.name == "Error"
      break
    else 
      object.elements.first.each do |innerObject| 
         printAllChildObjects(innerObject)
      end
    end
end
```

TL:DR; I 'm parsing some XML file with REXML (the XML parser that comes built-in with Ruby, I can't use Nokogiri for some ridiculous corporate reasons). This XML file has nodes that may or may not have children nodes nested within them, and a varying number of those at that. I tried my recursive function by using `puts` statements and observing the terminal, and it works as expected.

BUT, when I try to incorporate the above view file, I instead get empty boxes with three dots instead, i.e., `[ ... ]` where each object should be printed. The crazy thing is, the number of boxes matches the number of objects and upon inspecting the html with Chrome Dev Tools, you can see  the ENTIRE object node instead of just the `object.attributes['name']` (i.e just the name attribute in the node).

ALSO, when I remove the recursion call, and just keep the `"<li>#{object.attributes['name']}</li>"` part in the function, the HTML works again! So I'm fairly certain the recursion is what is breaking the HTML rendering. Is there some sort of way to get around this? I'd appreciate even the slightest insights.

Oh, and I'm using Sinatra, not Rails.

Comment: Ruby returns the last evaluated expression if there's not anything explicitly returned. You should continue to append to an object and return it if explicitly you don't want to concat to view's output buffer.

Comment: I think what're getting is because `object.elements.first.each` is returning the three objects, which that's how `.each` works.  Try changing `.each` for a `.collect`. That might not be all  you nee though.

Comment: @JoshBrody Have you heard of an alternative to `concat` for plain Ruby since that's a Rails method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the advice of appending to a certain HTML buffer and making explicit function returns, the following piece of code solved my problem:

```
def printAllChildObjects(refObject, html)
  html << "<li>#{refObject.attributes['name']}</li>"

  if refObject.children.first.name == "Error"
     break
  else
     refObject.elements.first.each do |innerObject|
         return printAllChildObjects(innerObject, html)
     end
  end

 return html
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like:

```
<ul>
  <% @objects.each do |object| %>
    <% print_children_for(object).flatten.each |li_tag| %>
     <%= li_tag %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</ul>

def print_children_for(object, parent = nil)
  mark_up = []
  mark_up << parent.nil? ? "<li>#{object.attributes['name']}</li>" : parent

  return mark_up if object.children.first.name == "Error"
  object.elements.first.each do |innerObject| 
     print_children_for(innerObject, markup)
  end
end
```

There are a few tweaks to be done (protecting for `nil` values in some places), I'm doing this on the fly, without checking it, but maybe something like that can help you.